# preg_match_all on the same line

Tags: php, preg-match-all, implode

i have:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/performers/test-1/" title="">test 1</a>                                <a href="http://www.test.com/performers/test-2/" title="">test 2</a>
```

I would like title 1,title 2 as result.

I wrote:

```
$m=array();
preg_match_all('/<a href="http:\/\/www.test.com\/performers\/(.*)\/" title="">(.*)<\/a>/i', $buff,$m);
$info['models'] = implode(',', $m[2]);
```

I get only title 2 as result.

But if title 1 and title 2 html codes are not on the same line, i get title 1,title 2.

How to get title 1,title 2 as result when all the html code is on the same line?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using a DOM parser instead of regex for HTML. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is greedyness of regex. The `(.)*` part in your regex matches `test-1/" title="">test 1</a> <a href="http://www.test.com/performers/test-2` instead of only `test-1`. If you add the modifyier `U` to your pattern your regex works. But you should escape some more characters in your regexp, i.e. all dots match any character, not only a dot:

```
$m = array();
preg_match_all('/<a\ href="http:\/\/www\.test\.com\/performers\/(.*)\/"\ title="">(.*)<\/a>/Ui', $buff,$m);
$info['models'] = implode(',', $m[2]);
```

And, to be fair, working on DOM would be much safer here.